# How can I use Room's @Relation annotation with composite keys for constructing Models?

Tags: android, foreign-keys, android-room, composite-primary-key

I have entity with composite primary key (ids of another two entities) and entity which has relation with first as one-to-many (so second entity has composite foreign key).

I'd like to use @Relation to construct model class, but that annotation has only one parent and one entity column as parameters. I need something like that:

```
@Relation(parentColumn = {id_part_1, id_part_2},
          entityColumn ={compose_key_part_1, compose_key_part_2},
          entity = ItemEntity.class)
private List<ItemModel> actions;
```

So, please, which way could I make models for entities with composite key?